# Multiple Network Interface Not Working Properly

Tags: centos, routing

I have two network interfaces on my Linux CentOS. When I tried to access the web server from outside network via **ETH0** it works properly. But when I tried to access via **ETH1** it gives me time out.

Here is the route:

```
[root@fe fe]# ip route list
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 101
default via 192.168.18.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 102
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.237 metric 101
192.168.18.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.18.14 metric 102
```

This is the `ip a` command produce

```
[fe@fe ~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:ce:a3:6d:a2:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.237/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 416sec preferred_lft 416sec
    inet6 fe80::d0ce:a3ff:fe6d:a2f4/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:be:5d:40:8b:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.18.14/24 brd 192.168.18.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 3584sec preferred_lft 3584sec
    inet6 fe80::88be:5dff:fe40:8b34/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can confirm the ETH1 receive the request using tcpdump.

```
[root@fe fe]# tcpdump -i eth1 port 80
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:04:57.763317 IP 43.224.168.199.50770 > fe.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 2609591301, win 64240, options [mss 1412,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:04:57.764527 IP 43.224.168.199.50771 > fe.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 821872254, win 64240, options [mss 1412,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
22:04:58.021494 IP 43.224.168.199.50772 > fe.lan.http: Flags [S], seq 3220097528, win 64240, options [mss 1412,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

Comment: Do you know what ip and port your web server is listening on? It's difficult to say with such limited information. Also if you can give the output of `ip a` of the webserver, just the private IP addresses.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam I already update the questions. For the web port is 80.

Comment: Your webserver may only be listening on eth0 192.168.10.237 port 80, in which case HTTP traffic would be flowing to the physical server, but your application won't receive the traffic. Is this an Apache/Nginx server?

Comment: @TimothyPulliam I don't think so, because when I switch the metric for 192.168.18.14 to 100 it working for eth1. But the eth0 now time out.